How to get/retrieve the values of a specific field of a webpage loaded in Internet Explorer mode in Edge browser?
I am trying to retrieve the value of a specific field of a webpage which is loaded in Internet Explorer within Edge Browser. I am trying to use Edge_GetIE function for this purpose. iWB2 Learner tool is showing this information about that field-
my codes are these-
f1::
edgePID:=Edge_Create()

pwb:=Edge_GetIE()
MsgBox % pwb.document.all.tags("IFRAME"[0].contentWindow.document.getElementById("startDate_ui").InnerText
return




Edge_create(neww = false){
    static edgePID
    IF !WinExist("ahk_exe msedge.exe") || neww {
        run msedge.exe,,,edgePID
        winWaitActive, ahk_pid %edgePiD%,,5
        
        
    }
    else {
        winget,edgePID,PID,ahk_exe msedge.exe
    }
    
    return edgePID
    
    
}
Edge_Quit(edgePID = false){
    
    criteria := edgePID ? edgePID : Edge_Create()
    for obj in ComObjGet("winmgmts:").ExecQuery("Select * from Win32_Process Where processID = " criteria) {
        obj.terminate()
    }
    
}

Edge_GetIE(edgePID = false){
    static IID_IWebDOCUMENT := "{332C4425-26CB-11D0-B483-00C04FD90119}"
    static counter = 0
    window := "ahk_class Chrome_WidgetWin_1 ahk_exe msedge.exe ahk_pid " pid := edgePID ? edgePID : Edge_Create()
    msgbox % window
    ;msg := WM_HTML_GETOBJECT()
    msg := WM_HTML_GETOBJECT()
    SendMessage msg, 0, 0, Internet Explorer_Server1, %window%
    if (ErrorLevel != "FAIL"){
        lResult := ErrorLevel
        VarSetCapacity( GUID, 16, 0 )
        if DllCall( "ole32\CLSIDFromString", "wstr", IID_IWebDOCUMENT, "ptr", &GUID ) >= 0 {
            DllCall( "oleacc\ObjectFromLresult", "ptr", lResult, "ptr", &GUID, "ptr", 0, "ptr*", IWebDOCUMENT )
            try {
                pwb := IWebBrowserApp_from_IWebDOCUMENT( IWebDOCUMENT )
                counter := 0
                ToolTip
            }
            return  pwb
        }else
            errorMSG := "no CLSIDFromString"
    }else
        errorMSG :=  "FAIL"
    
    if  (counter++ < 10){ ;try up to 10 times to connect to IE
        ToolTip * %counter% * %pid% * retyring %errorMSG%
        sleep 1000
        return Edge_GetIE()
    }
    ToolTip
    msgbox %errorMSG%
}

WM_HTML_GETOBJECT(){
    return DllCall( "RegisterWindowMessage", "str", "WM_HTML_GETOBJECT" )
}

IWebBrowserApp_from_IWebDOCUMENT( IWebDOCUMENT ){
    static IID_IWebBrowserApp := "{0002DF05-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}"  ; IID_IWebBrowserApp
    return ComObj(9,ComObjQuery( IHTMLWindow2_from_IWebDOCUMENT( IWebDOCUMENT ), IID_IWebBrowserApp, IID_IWebBrowserApp),1)
}

IHTMLWindow2_from_IWebDOCUMENT( IWebDOCUMENT ){
    static IID_IHTMLWindow2 := "{332C4427-26CB-11D0-B483-00C04FD90119}"  ; IID_IHTMLWindow2
    return ComObj(9,ComObjQuery( IWebDOCUMENT, IID_IHTMLWindow2, IID_IHTMLWindow2),1)
}

The above codes are showing an empty message box while it should show 11-09-2024
Please tell me where I am wrong in the above codes..
Thanks a lot
I want to retrieve the value of that specific field into messagebox as shown above.

Sorry but at this point I would switch up to python. It has selenium which works a lot better than what ahk can achieve.
